# Text binding with knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, typescript

I have implemented drop down control which bind with data object that
looks like

```
[{id:1,name:"ABC"},
{id:2,name:"XYZ"}]
```

and also implemented data-bind="value: Name" using knockout, now
problem is when i change drop down option it always give me id not its
name not sure why since i am exclusively setting text to view model
property.Can you please tell me what is the issue?

Thanks

> My Code is

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.id, Model.MyObject, string.Empty, new { data_bind = "value: name", Id = "ddList", style = "width: 200px;font-size: 20px" })%>

module TestModule{
    export class TestViewModel {


            public name: KnockoutObservable<string>;                


            constructor() {

                this.name = ko.observable();
            }

        }
    export class TestClass {        


            name: KnockoutObservable<string>;      

            Constructor() {

                this.name = ko.observable();                      
            }   
}
```

Comment: Please post your html with the KO bindings!

Comment: Did you have a chance to check how it works here?
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Comment: Please check i added my code above.I am using TypeScript and Knockout and MVC3.

Answer (score 0):

If your object looks like this:

```
[{id:1,name:"ABC"},
{id:2,name:"XYZ"}]
```

And you're using this for data binding:

```
data-bind="value: Name"
```

Then is it a case issue, the binding is case-sensitive so just change `Name` to lowercase `name`:

```
data-bind="value: name"
```

Comment: that was the only example i gave, i am taking care of case, i added some sample code please look into that so u can get batter idea what i am doing.